# Memory allocating array of structure pointers in c

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures

I'd like to pass an array of pointers of structure addresses which has varying size and access structure members. But by passing the array of structure objects the data is irregular and library functions are giving SIGABRT signal.
This is a part of my code-

```
struct data *device_info;

device_info = malloc(device_count*sizeof(void );
ipbt_database_manager_get_device_info(device_info, "all", device_count);
```

This is the function definition-

```
bool ipbt_database_manager_get_device_info(struct data *dev_info_ptr, char *device_id, int device_count)
{
    struct node *current_device_info = first_device_info;
    int count = 0;

    if (!strcmp(device_id,"all")) {
        while (current_device_info != NULL) {
            dev_info_ptr[count] = current_device_info->node_data;
            count++;
            current_device_info = current_device_info->next;
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious. What do you think `sizeof(void)` is supposed to give you?

Comment: It gives enough space to store address of structure right? size of void is 4 bytes.

Comment: Where is node struct declared ?

Comment: @Govindh Replace that with `sizeof(struct data)`

Comment: node struct id declared and malloc' ed in a different c file. It is an existing database ie a linked list.

Comment: @Govindh - Sure it's 4 bytes, it's also 8 and 16. Does a type without values can have any meaningful size?

Comment: @StoryTeller i tried replacing it with sizeof(int). Same response.

Comment: @Govindh  *It gives enough space to store address of structure right?* Maybe, maybe not.  Because `void` is *not* a type.  But it certainly *doesn't* give enough size to store a `struct data` via `dev_info_ptr[count] = current_device_info->node_data;`, even if `count` is `0`.  And once `count` is greater than zero, the assignment will certainly overwrite unallocated memory.

Comment: i just need to store the starting address of the structure in that array. I can access the structure again by dereferencing the pointer right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function expects a pointer to a structure, (possibly one of many the lie in consecutive memory).

This should allocate enough memory, which is the memory for a single `struct data` times `device_count`:

```
struct data *device_info = malloc(sizeof(*device_info) * device_count);
ipbt_database_manager_get_device_info(device_info, "all", device_count);
```

I omitted that check for NULL (which you must preform), and I united the pointer definition with its initialization.

Comment: Does it copy the data to newly allocated memory or just copy the address of the original database(structure)?

Comment: @Govindh - It passes a consecutive buffer to `ipbt_database_manager_get_device_info`.

Comment: I just need to save the starting addresses of the structure database,not the whole thing. Is there any way to do that.

Comment: @StoryTeller Curious, any particular reason for `malloc(count * sizeof *ptr)` vs. `malloc(sizeof *ptr * count)`?  I find the 2nd form better when `malloc(sizeof *ptr * row * col)` insures at least `size_t` math throughout the product calculation.

Comment: @chux - personal style preference. I just find the second form odd to read when the asterisk serves different purposes. Operator precedence while correct doesn't feel "natural" to me.

Comment: Good answer.  I agree about the odd-ness.  Yet found in the 3 operand multiply `int row,col` and `malloc(row * col * sizeof *ptr)`  `row*col` may overflow yet not in `malloc(sizeof *ptr * row * col)` so I tend to `sizeof()` first, even with only 2 operands.

Comment: @chux - Yes, adding `()` is actually a good solution to the weirdness. The extra characters are a small price to pay for correct arithmetic. I will definitely adopt that advice, thank you.